# Keras custom loss class distribution

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I want to add a factor to the categorical_crossentropy loss. It would describe the class distribution of y_pred compared to a reference. A simplified example:

```
y_ref = [5, 45, 30, 20] 
y_pred = [10, 40, 30, 20]
factor = 10
```

At the moment I only use this factor as a metric. I run a prediction on the training data to verify the factor's accuracy. The value is incorrect.

I tried to return the totalsum_pred which should be the number of samples in y_pred. However the class_f and the val_class_f are not round numbers (like 31.9701). I am not using batches or regularization.

What is the problem?

```
def class_f(y_true, y_pred):

    ref_rate = K.cast([0.05, 0.45, 0.30, 0.20], dtype='float32')

    pred_cast = K.cast(y_pred, dtype='float32')    
    pred_argmax = K.argmax(pred_cast, axis=1)
    pred_onehot = K.one_hot(pred_argmax , 4)

    sum_pred = K.sum(pred_onehot, axis=0)
    totalsum_pred = K.sum(pred_onehot)
    norm_sum_pred = K.cast(sum_pred / totalsum_pred, dtype='float32')

    class_factor = K.sum(K.abs(ref_rate-norm_sum_pred))

    return class_factor 

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[class_f])
```

Answer (score 0):

Default batch_size doesn't work for this code. I set my batch_size to the number of train samples in the model.fit function.